# How to post list in drf post request via postman

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman

I have a client model that can have multiple numbers like a person can have multiple phone numbers.
I want to create a client in my database plus add all of its phone numbers at the same time. just like when a person submits his data in a form.

Right now I testing my API in postman but could submit data when number field is added in serializer, GET request is working but I am struggling with post

models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    departure = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True)
    arrival = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Number(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='number')
```

serializers.py

```
class NumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Number
        fields = ('id', 'number')

class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    number = NumberSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'departure', 'arrival', 'price','number')
```

views.py

```
class ClientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

This is how I am making a post request via postman and getting error

[image: postman post request parameters and error]

Answer (score 1):

[image]you have to send in json instead of form-data[image: you have to send in json instead of form-data]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to override the `create` method to make [writable nested serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers):

```
class NumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Number
        fields = ('id', 'number')

class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    number = NumberSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'departure', 'arrival', 'price','number')
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        number_data = validated_data.pop('number')
        number = Number.objects.create(**number_data)
        client = Client.objects.create(number=number, **validated_data)
        return client
```